# How to change default post url in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url, post, domain-name

not sure how to get around this one. Anyways so I am working on a WP blog http://athenasweb.com

However every post I make the url is not athenasweb, but instead 1and1's default URL before the domain name was switched over:
http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/

This is really annoying especially when linking to new posts, anyway to change this in wordpress?

Example this: http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/aspectarian-nov-2nd-nov-8th-2012/

Should be http://athenasweb.com/aspectarian-nov-2nd-nov-8th-2012/

[image]

Comment: Go to general settings and make sure the wordpress address and site address match what you want it to be.

Comment: Ah thanks! I'm such a WP noob :( can you make this an answer so I can select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to general settings and make sure the wordpress address and site address match what you want it to be.